# Do we really need a new physics?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, space-expansion, big-bang, observable-universe

I have heard many times in news that a new discovery has taken place, and we need a new physics.

It has recently been announced in scientific news that the world is apparently expanding faster.

And guess what? Everyone says we need a new physics!
I'm also interested in having a new physics, but we did not have a new physics in the past 100 years!.

Anyway, what does it mean that the universe is expanding so fast and we need a new physics?

Do we have such things as new physics or old one?

Do we really need a new physics (whatever the circumstance)?

---

Ref. [The Universe Is Expanding So Fast We Might Need New Physics to Explain It](https://www.space.com/universe-expanding-fast-new-physics.html)

Comment: I think with "new physics" they simply mean a new research field within physics or a new theory. In the case you are citing the latter is the case, as current theories are not able to explain the observations.

Comment: If you read the article, instead of just quoting the title, then it's about the model being incomplete : "that we’re missing something in the cosmological model". So new theory or better detail in existing theory.

Comment: At present no-one knows, so any answers to this question can only be opinion not fact. There are experimental tensions in the value of the Hubble constant (I assume you mean this when you talk about *the world is apparently expanding faster*) but we don't know whether this indicates a fundamental problem with the cosmological standard model or not.

Comment: "but we did not have a new physics in the past 100 years!" Well, probably you personally did not:P

Comment: "New physics" is a jargon expression especially loved by high energy physicists - but not alone. It's used every time observation or experiment seemingly don't fit into established theory. With little concern as to how deeply the disagreement would affect physics. Add journalistic emphasis... So you'd better to take such declarations with a grain of salt. This said, the discourse would be very long and surely OT for this site.

Comment: @OON This is the result of the research carried out in this regard [1905–1930: The Golden Age of Physics](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-3936-3_1) or [Golden age of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_age_of_physics)

Comment: @TheLastJedi and everything afterwards was trivial... Yeah, sure. It ends in 30 mostly because people usually have no clue what happened afterwards.